# How to filter entity datasource base on year if I have the date

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have an entity which has the following columns:

1. ID
2. Name
3. Value
4. Date

I need to put a where condition in the entity data-source, something like:

```
          year(it.Date)=@year   -- is not working !!!
```

I tried into the Select:

```
           Select year(it.Date) as xYear...
```

then in Where condition I put:

```
           it.xYear = @year   --- is not working !!!
```

Can someone give me a solution?

I want to insert a where statement in the EntityDatasource - Property Window.

**EDIT**

I did it by using a custom query.

```
      <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=MyEmmoAppEntities" DefaultContainerName="MyEmmoAppEntities" EnableFlattening="False" 
Where="" CommandText="select kpivalues .idkpi,kpivalues .ivalue,kpivalues .[date] from kpivalues where year(kpivalues .[date])=2015 and month(kpivalues .[date])=2">
                            </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this for code behind:

```
int year=2015;
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM table it WHERE year(it.Date)=@year";
SqlDataSourceArticole.Parameters.Add("@year", System.Data.DbType.Int32, year);
```

You can specify the WhereParameter in the aspx-File

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="SearchEntityDataSource" runat="server" 
    .....        
    Where="year(it.Date) = @year" >
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="SearchYearTextBox" Name="year" PropertyName="Text" 
         Type="Int32" DefaultValue="2015"/>
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
<asp:TextBox ID="SearchYearTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

In [this](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-3) article you can find more details

Comment: Thanks Mega, can you give me a solution which can be applied with entity framework? the code posted in the question was input in the Entitydatasource properties window, and I wish if you can give me a solution for this approach.

Comment: You can configure that in Entitydatasource properties window or in aspx-File @LucianBumb

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
it.TableName.Where(x=>x.date==@year);
```

Comment: I need to put this condition in the where property of the EntityDatasource1. Can you help me?

Comment: Not working, need to put this condition in the Where property window of  EntityDatasource.

Comment: @LucianBumb Sorry for that. I were thinking that you are using asp.net mvc. Can you put   EntityDatasource code in your question ?

Comment: I have no code, I just add it on the web form and configure it with wizard.

Comment: @LucianBumb : "I have no code". You have code!!!! Open the aspx file. How you can developing without code???